# How many questions are we answering?

Tags: discussion, data

recently I have been feeling that **we are not answering a lot of question**, firstly because there are lots of "close"-worthy questions and secondly because many questions can be solved by only a few people(example, a question related to using a specific hardware will probably be solvable by only someone who uses it.)

Anyway, can someone pull out statistics regarding how many question have been answered, in the last

- 1 month
- 3 months
- 6 months
- 1 year

Also is it possible to consider whether the question was closed or not, and whether the answer was accepted or not.

Once this data is pulled, we could discuss the issue(if it even exists).

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/303570/answer-rate-over-time#graph) lists count of questions total,  questions answered and questions closed by month. Make of it what you will.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the data. It looks like the rate of answering question has declined from about 70% in May 14 to 50% last month. It also comes out that number of questions asked has also declined in the same time. There might be some relation between this.

Comment: And other sites do seem to be doing better.

Comment: Be careful with comparisons with May '14. An LTS release had just happened, so the number of upgrades would be higher than usual. And April's data would be incomplete, and we have a new release to come. Check again at in June.